# Correcto uso de ORDEN BY CASE Sqlite Python

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

estoy trabajando sobre una base de datos Sqlite3 con Python que contiene, entre otras cosas, notas numéricas cuando existen y un valor "-" cuando no existe. Las mismas estan almacenadas en una columna `nota` de la tabla `plan`. Al momento de crear un filtro para mostrarle al usuario, quiero que las notas numéricas se ordenen de mayor a menor y, al terminar estas, se enumeren las notas que tienen el valor "-". Intenté con `Order By CASE ... THEN` pero no logro hacerlo funcionar como debería.

```
db_rows = database.run_query("SELECT * FROM plan ORDER BY CASE nota WHEN '-' THEN 99 END, nota")
```

Aclaro que entiendo que luego de `THEN` correspondería colocar el orden de prioridad que debería tomar el dato con este valor, por lo que le doy prioridad 99 para que se coloque en última posición, ya que habrá menos de 99 datos en la tabla.
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Asumo que el campo es un String, en ese caso solo usando `ORDER BY nota` (sin el CASE) debería funcionar. Aunque si los números se pasan de 10 y los menores no tienen 0's al principio, no se va a ordenar bien si es que está guardado como texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solución

Lo que pasa es que a tu case le falta el else o está mal formado. Esta sería la versión completa del case (asumiendo que nota es de tipo integer):

```
"SELECT * FROM plan ORDER BY CASE nota WHEN '-' THEN 99 ELSE nota END
```

Si nota no es de tipo integer, nos toca convertirlo en entero con `cast(nota AS integer)` para que se ordene correctamente. El texto se ordena de manera distinta que los números, por lo que ordenar usando texto no nos sirve.

#### Una estructura alternativa para la tabla

Las bases de datos no suelen aceptar datos de dos tipos diferentes (como un numero y la cadena '-'), si no que tratan de convertir el dato al mismo tipo que la columna. Sin embargo, si aceptan que se ingrese null en ellas. Sqlite3, Postgresql y MySql permiten null en una columna numerica y Sqlite3 es la excepción y acepta datos de distinto tipo. [comprobado](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d2AQq3yUanHeeGz5XFjZhB/0).

Asumiendo que la columna es de tipo integer, que la nota es null cuando no existe y no usas `SELECT *` (lo cual [suele considerarse mala practica](https://betterprogramming.pub/using-select-in-an-sql-query-is-a-bad-practice-a8f6beeca1da), excepto cuando se usa para probar cosas), podríamos usar una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT COALESCE(nota, '-') FROM plan ORDER BY COALESCE(nota, 99)
```

Como habrás notado, estamos usando una función llamada `coalesce`. El proposito de esta función es devolvernos el primero de sus argumentos que NO sea null.

Sabiendo el proposito de coalesce, podríamos decir que lo que hace esta consulta es seleccionar la nota, si nota es null, coalesce pasa al siguiente argumento, que obviamente nunca será null: '-'.
Esta consulta es ordenada por la columna nota cuando no es null. Si la columna es null, entonces se ordena por el numero 99.

Nota: Si tomas este enfoque, lo mejor será que modifiques las partes de tu programa donde ingresas la nota para que ingrese null en los casos correspondientes.